# Close the Chrome Extension automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, auto-close

I am trying to close the extension automatically after saving my data.

Here is the code which is used to save the data:

```
$(function(){

    function  displayMessage(string){
        alert(string);
    }

    var submit = $('#submit');
    $('#create').submit(function(){
        $('#loading_image').html('<img src="images/wait.gif">');
        var user_email = localStorage.getItem('email');
        var api = localStorage.getItem("user_api_key");
        var auth = "apikey" +' ' +(user_email+":"+api);
        var favicon_key = localStorage.getItem("favicon_image_key");
        var peoples = [];
        var tags_peoples = $("#s2id_people .select2-choices .select2-search-choice");
        for (i=0; i<tags_peoples.length; i++) {
            peoples.push({"label": tags_peoples[i].childNodes[1].textContent})
        }
        var subjects = [];
        var tags_subjects = $("#s2id_subjects .select2-choices .select2-search-choice");
        for (i=0; i<tags_subjects.length;i++) {
            subjects.push({"label": tags_subjects[i].childNodes[1].textContent})
        }
        var places = [];
        var tags_places = $("#s2id_places .select2-choices .select2-search-choice");
        for (i=0; i<tags_places.length; i++) {
            places.push({"label": tags_places[i].childNodes[1].textContent})
        }
        var begin = $(".daterangepicker_start_input")[0].childNodes[1].value;
        var end = $(".daterangepicker_end_input")[0].childNodes[1].value;
        var data = {
            'content': $('#title').val(),
            'people': peoples,
            'subjects': subjects,
            'begin_date': begin,
            'end_date': end,
            'places': places
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
            },
            url: "https://my_site_url/api/v3/data/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading_image').hide();
                window.location.href = 'saved.html';
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.close();
                }, 2000);               
            },

            error: function(data) {
                $('#div1').text("Error on saving the data");
                $('#loading_image').hide();
            },
            complete: function() {
                submit.removeAttr('disabled').text('Save');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I am using this to close the extension

```
setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 3000);
```

But this doesn't work. Should I write any EventListener to close the extension automatically?

Appreciated the answers

Comment: Define "close the extension". The popup window? And how are you "saving your data"?

Comment: Hi @Xan . Updated the code of saving the data. Please check

Comment: Yep, that was the missing piece. Next time you make a question, consider reading the [How to Ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this snippet from your code:

```
window.location.href = 'saved.html';
setTimeout(function(){
  window.close();
}, 2000);
```

This will not work. As soon as you change location, the page starts to navigate away, eventually wiping the `window` state and all timeouts set when the new page loads.

You need to set the timeout from `saved.html` for this to work.

Comment: So, if I write the setTimeout in one js file and load it in the saved.html, then will it work?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.